# Ajax code wont work first time, then it works

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using service bus to to send and recive orderId from other project. My Ajax code dosn't work on the first try, but after the first attempt, it works fine.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "/Home/readFromQueue"; //reading from ASB, get orderId

        function getData() {
            $.get(url, function(data) { 

                var id = data;       

                 //NewOrder in controller wont run for the first time
                 $.post("/Home/NewOrder", { "id": id }, 
                      function(data) { ...
```

Is there any wrong with my Ajax code? In debugg mode, `ReadFromQueue` works fine and pass correct `Id`(at first try). But `NewOrder` won't run in the first try. But then it works fine if I try again.

EDIT:

My current code:

```
var url = "/Home/readFromQueue";
function getData() {
    $.get(url, function(data) {    

        var id = data;                      
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Home/NewOrder",
                    data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.
You should call this function on click event

```
function sendData(){
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "yoururlhere",
          data: "{'data1':'" + value1+ "', 'data2':'" + value2+ "', 'data3':'" + value3+ "'}",
          success: function (result) {
               //do somthing here
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: Is `data` what I send to parameter in controller? E.g. `Id` etc

Comment: You need to add like this
 data: "{'id':'" + $id+ "'}",

Comment: I applied your code, but it doesn't work. Can you check if I did something wrong? I updated my question with my current code,

Comment: Pass your id in the function parameter

function getData(id) {
        var id = data;                      
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",                 
                    url: "/Home/NewOrder",
                    data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {...

Comment: I'm confused. It says `Id` in parameter is never used. What should I do with  "/Home/readFromQueue" where it gets it Id?

Comment: I think you are beginner first you can add id parameter where you are calling this function. After that you can pass id in data .